# comparing items in list of keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values for each keys as list of items. I want to compare the item at every index in the list of every key in dictionary and check if it is identical or not.

```
dict1=OrderedDict([('A1', ['G', 'N', 'K', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'E', 'L']), 
                   ('B1', ['G', 'N', 'K', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'E', 'L']), 
                   ('C1', ['G', 'N', 'R', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'R', 'L'])])
```

I would like to check if index 0 in the list of key `A1` is similar to index 0 in keys `B1` and `C1`. Similarly, I want to check for every index in key `A1` the respective index in the list of other keys are the same or not.

I tried but could not compare the index for each key in the dictionary.

Comment: What output do you expect? Just the number of the indices that differs? Or these that are the same? Or the letters that are different?

Comment: You can try converting the list to an array, then use hash() to hash this array and then check all keys have same hash values.

I am not on python 2.7 anymore, so did not try myself. But if it works share the code here.

Comment: Thanks Trasha for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I wanted to identify the identical items.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together and then compare each element to each corresponding elements.

```py
dict1=OrderedDict([('A1', ['G', 'N', 'K', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'E', 'L']), 
                   ('B1', ['G', 'N', 'K', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'E', 'L']), 
                   ('C1', ['G', 'N', 'R', 'G', 'I', 'R', 'R', 'L'])])

for i, elems in enumerate(zip(*dict1.values())):
    print "%d %s" % (i, elems)
    if any(elems[0] != check_elem for check_elem in elems[1:]):
        print "The key A1 is different at index %d" % (i)
```

And this gives:

```
0 ('G', 'G', 'G')
1 ('N', 'N', 'N')
2 ('K', 'K', 'R')
The key A1 is different at index 2
3 ('G', 'G', 'G')
4 ('I', 'I', 'I')
5 ('R', 'R', 'R')
6 ('E', 'E', 'R')
The key A1 is different at index 6
7 ('L', 'L', 'L')
```

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo. I wanted a similar output. but the number of keys in dictionary can vary based on the dataset i use. So in such case can i use elems[1:] != elems[:-1]?

Comment: No that won't exactly work. I will update my answer. But do you always want to compare the `A1` list compared with all others?